# Resharper patterns: string to type in generic method

Tags: c#, resharper, resharper-7.1

Simply put, is it possible to use patterns in Resharper to do the following replacement:

Before:

```
AddType("MyApplication.Something.SomeObject", "ObjectName");
```

After

```
AddType<MyApplication.Something.SomeObject>("ObjectName");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but this won't work, mainly because SSR does not have a concept of a *literal*, and specifying arguments as `AddType("$FOO$", "$BAR$")` will not result in a successful match if `$FOO$` and `$BAR$` are declared as argument placeholders.

Comment: Well, that's regrettable. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. You have two options: use a regular expression (probably easier) or write a ReSharper plugin to do this (somewhat harder).